# jQuery Tic-Tac-Toe infinite loop warning on codePen

Tags: javascript, jquery, tic-tac-toe, codepen

here my attempt on supposedly light  [TIC-TAC-TOE](https://codepen.io/sanchopanza/pen/WLGxxq) like game. 
 On CodePen game sometimes crashes showing this infinite loop warning while breaking win logic. Can't seem to figure out why

[image: picture of error on codePen]
I cant seem to be able to break it on offline machine and cant think of reasons why infinite loop would be appearing online..

```
//Tic Tac Toe Simple Game less then 50 lines 
//of code
//simple jquery tic-tac style game with aim 
//at short easy css modifiebly code
//@sanchopanza
var gameOver = false;
var playerTurn = 1;
var playerAMoves = [];
var playerBMoves = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) { //generate map
  $(".map").append('<div class="box" id="loadID""></div>');
  $("#loadID").attr("id", i);
}
$(".box").click(function() {
  if (gameOver === false && $("#" + this.id).text() == "") {
    if (playerTurn === 1) {
      $("#" + this.id).append('<div class="crissCross">0</div>');
      playerAMoves.push(this.id);
      playerTurn = 2;
      gameEnd();
      return;
    }
    if (playerTurn === 2) {
      $("#" + this.id).append('<div class="crissCross">X</div>');
      playerBMoves.push(this.id);
      playerTurn = 1;
      gameEnd();
      return;
    }
  };
})

function gameEnd() {
  var player;
  if (playerTurn === 2) {
    player = playerAMoves;
  };
  if (playerTurn === 1) {
    player = playerBMoves;
  };
  if (containsAll(["1", "5", "9"], player) === true) {
    winnerWinner();
    return;
  };
  if (containsAll(["3", "5", "7"], player) === true) {
    winnerWinner();
    return;
  };
  if (containsAll(["1", "2", "3"], player) === true) {
    winnerWinner();
    return;
  };
  if (containsAll(["4", "5", "6"], player) === true) {
    winnerWinner();
    return;
  };
  if (containsAll(["7", "8", "9"], player) === true) {
    winnerWinner();
    return;
  };
  if (containsAll(["1", "4", "7"], player) === true) {
    winnerWinner();
    return;
  };
  if (containsAll(["2", "5", "8"], player) === true) {
    winnerWinner();
    return;
  };
  if (containsAll(["3", "6", "9"], player) === true) {
    winnerWinner();
    return;
  };
  if (playerAMoves.length + playerBMoves.length === 9) {
    $(".map").css("height", "370px").append("PARITY");
    return;
  }
};

function containsAll(winCombi, playerMoves) { //locator
  for (var i = 0, len = winCombi.length; i < len; i++) {
    if ($.inArray(winCombi[i], playerMoves) == -1) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function winnerWinner() {
  gameOver = true;
  if (playerTurn === 2) {
    $(".map").css("height", "370px").append("CIRCLE WINS");
    return;
  } else {
    $(".map").css("height", "370px").append("CROSS WINS");
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any infinite loop. There are only 2 loops, they're both simple `for` loops that should always end. What do I have to do to get CodePen to show that error?

Comment: Same for me ,I dont understand where infinite loop comes from.I just stress play it and sometimes get wrong game logic - (ex. Cross wins ,when in reality it's parity etc.) while receiving this error. I can upload a screenshot if needed

Comment: BTW, get in the habit of using `else if` for mutually exclusive tests in successive `if` statements, and `else` when the second test is the only other possibility.

Comment: And don't use `x === true` and `x === false`. Use `if (x)` and `if (!x)`.

Comment: I've played about 10 games and haven't gotten an incorrect result or that warning yet. If you can't provide a reproducible error, it's going to be hard to answer this.

Comment: Thank you for tips. if(x) are pretty handy - changed the code and its working like a charm. And by the habit of using "else if" - do you mean just always using "else if" if having multiple choice but one possible outcome? I was using return inside if statements in order to try just termination execution of future if statements. And about codePen - Yeah its weird error, ill try to figure out occasions it occurs more often

Comment: I would probably combine all of those into a single `if`: `if (containsAll(["1", "5", "9"], player) || containsAll(["3", "5", "7"], player) || ...)` since the results are all the same.

Comment: You could also define an array of all the winning plays, and then write `if (winning_plays.any(play => containsAll(play, player)))`

Comment: Thanks, I used your suggestion, looks better and idea with defining winning plays is cool I will try it later. Still tho I get that infinite loop error every once in a while, I will try using different computer or device, to see maybe its just my browser bug

Comment: So yeah after checking more closely problem occurs only on Chrome browser

Comment: I use Chrome as well. This might be relevant: https://blog.codepen.io/2016/06/08/can-adjust-infinite-loop-protection-timing/